# How to mixin behavior using class decorators in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, decorator, mixins, python-decorators

I have a base class that has a lot of direct sub classes. There are multiple independent features that are shared by multiple of the sub classes. This is a good use case for Python's cooperative inheritance. However, the features should wrap behavior from the outside, so they need to be earlier in the method resolution order.

```
class WrappedSub(FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC, RealSub):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        FeatureA.__init__(foo=42)
        FeatureB.__init__(bar=13)
        FeatureC.__init__(foobar=546)
        RealSub.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class RealSub(Base):
    # Lots of code ...
```

It would be nice to decorate the child classes instead.

```
@Mixin(FeatureA, 42)
@Mixin(FeatureB, 13)
@Mixin(FeatureC, 546)
class RealSub(Base):
    # Lots of code ...
```

Precisely, I need a `@Mixin` decorator where the first block below is be equivalent to the second.

```
@Mixin(Sub, *feature_args, **feature_kwargs)
class RealSub:
    # Lots of code ...

class RealSub:
    # Lots of code ...
class WrappedSub(Feature, RealSub):
    def __init__(self, *sub_args, **sub_kwargs):
        Feature.__init__(self, *feature_args, **feature_kwargs)
        RealSub.__init__(self, *sub_args, **sub_kwargs)
RealSub = WrappedSub
```

How is this possible in Python 3?

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use Python's cooperative multiple-inheritance system to write your mixin classes, rather than trying to implement them as class decorators. This is how I've generally understood the term "mixin" to be used in Python OOP.

```
class Base:
    def method(self, param):
        value = param + 18
        return value

class FeatureOne:               # this could inherit from Base 
    def method(self, param):
        if param == 42:
            return 13
        else:
            return super().method(param)   # call next class in inheritance chain

class Child(FeatureOne, Base):
    def method(self, param):
        value = super().method(param)
        value *= 2
        return value
```

This isn't quite the same as what you wanted, since it calls the `FeatureOne` class's `method` implementation between the `Base` and `Child` classes' versions, rather than before `Child` does its thing. You could instead add an new `Grandchild` class that inherits from the `Feature`s you care about first, and `Child` last, if you can't adjust the methods to work in this order (the `Grandchild` class's body could be empty).

If you really want to use decorators to flip the order around, I think you could probably make it work, with the decorator building a "grandchild" class for you (though it doesn't know anything about the normal inheritance hierarchy). Here's a rough attempt at a `mixin` decorator that works almost like you want:

```
def mixin(*mixin_classes, **mixin_kwargs): # decorator factory function
    def decorator(cls): # decorator function
        class wrapper(*mixin_classes, cls):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                wrapped_kwargs = mixin_kwargs.copy() # use the passed kwargs to update the
                wrapped_kwargs.update(kwargs)        # mixin args, so caller can override
                super().__init__(*args, **wrapped_kwargs)
        # maybe modify wrapper's __name__, __qualname__, __doc__, etc. to match cls here?
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The mixin classes should call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` from their own `__init__` method (if they have one), but they can accept (and not pass on) keyword-only arguments of their own that they want to be passed by the `mixin` decorator:

```
class FeatureOne:
    def __init__(self, *args, foo, **kwargs): # note that foo is a keyword-only argument
        self.foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def method(self, param):
        if param == self.foo:
            return 13
        else:
            return super().__method__(param)

@mixin(FeatureOne, foo=42)
class Child(Base):
    def method(self, param):
        return super().method(param) * 2
```

The decorator should work either with all the mixin classes passed to one decorator call (e.g. `@mixin(FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC, foo=42, bar=13, foobar=546)`), or with several nested decorator calls. The MRO of the final class will be the same either way.

Comment: I thought about cooperative inheritance and updated the question. As you said, the problem is that features wrap the sub class behavior. Maybe cooperative inheritance can be combined with a `@Mixin` class decorator? Another idea would be to copy the wrapping feature class object and add the wrapped sub class to its `__bases__`. Do you think that could work?